# Sql Only Update not edit gridview using update button c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to update sql table then data can be bind when page postback. I dont want to edit in gridview.

My aspx code....

```
<asp:GridView ID="VRGridservicefee" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None"
    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No Records Added"
    DataKeyNames="V16_TRANID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1_V16_VEN_SER_FEE" OnRowUpdating="VRGridservicefee_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Delete"
                    OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Fee?');" /></ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="V16_TRANID" HeaderText="Vendor ser ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="V16_V13TRANID" HeaderText="Vendor ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="V16_SERVICES" HeaderText="Service" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="V16_CURRENCY" HeaderText="Service Currency" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="V16_FEES" HeaderText="Service Fees" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="V16_REM" HeaderText="Service Remarks" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"
            ItemStyle-Width="90 px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana"
        HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" Font-Names="Verdana" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" Font-Names="Verdana" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1_V16_VEN_SER_FEE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VMSTEST %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [V16_TRANID], [V16_V13TRANID], [V16_SERVICES], [V16_CURRENCY], [V16_FEES], [V16_REM] FROM [V16_VEN_SER_FEE] WHERE ([V16_V13TRANID] = @V16_V13TRANID) and V16_Status = 'A'">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="VDtranid" Name="V16_V13TRANID" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>                                              
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My .cs code for

```
protected void VRGridservicefee_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    //Label tranidid = VRGridservicefee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("V16_TRANID") as Label;
    //TextBox tranidid = (TextBox)VRGridservicefee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("V16_TRANID");
    int tranidid = Convert.ToInt32(VRGridservicefee.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    SqlCommand updategrid = new SqlCommand("update V16_VEN_SER_FEE set V16_STATUS='I' where V16_TRANID = @v16tranid", con);
    updategrid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v16tranid",tranidid);
    updategrid.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    VRGridservicefee.DataBind();

}
```

i need to take the particular row V16_tranid as where condition to update sql.. simple.. cant find any solution. want to do in only code behind.

Comment: It looks like that's what you're doing already.  Is this not working in some way?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1_V16_VEN_SER_FEE' unless UpdateCommand is specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

'Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1_V16_VEN_SER_FEE' unless UpdateCommand is specified.

Comment: Sql command working after it's throwing this error.